# View shares in powershell on remote computer that are visible from windows explorer

Tags: powershell, share

In windows explorer, I am able to type in `\\computer.domain\` and see certain shares on that computer. My user doesn't have access to those, but I can still see them in windows explorer. In powershell, if I start typing that, i.e. `dir \\computer.domain\`, intellisense will give me those same shares as options to complete the path with, but leaving the path as it is will result in a DNE error. Additionally, typing `Get-wmiobject win32_share -computername computer` will result in an access denied error. How can I access the names of those shares that intellisense and windows explorer can show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way that I know of to enumerate shares without using WMI which requires permissions on the remote machine and that is using the native command "net view"

```
net view \\computername
```

You will have to do some parsing with PowerShell if you want to manipulate those results and use it for something else. Since "net view" is not a PowerShell Cmdlet, instead a native windows console app command it returns text, not an object as would a powershell cmdlet would.  But it should get you started for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I only know the "net view" utility, but it won't list hidden shares (those which finish with '$'), although you can check their existant with Get-Acl specifying their names, for example:

```
Get-Acl \\192.168.0.1\admin$
```